# How can I convert date in a column to a epoch timestamp in bash?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a file containing this:

```
2014-11-10 02:00:03,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user2,192.168.203.63,10.146.124.73,59996,22
2014-11-10 02:00:07,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user1,172.24.31.10,172.32.1.1,48191,22
2014-11-10 02:00:11,LOGIN FAILED,AUTH,root,172.24.166.153,10.146.124.73,52506,22
```

I want to convert the timestamp to a date in this format:

```
1415602803,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user2,192.168.203.63,10.146.124.73,59996,22
1415602807,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user1,172.24.31.10,172.32.1.1,48191,22
1415602811,LOGIN FAILED,AUTH,root,172.24.166.153,10.146.124.73,52506,22
```

How can I achieve this using awk or any other bash tool.

**Background:**
I need to grab files from hdfs for a particular time range. Initially I was using *hdfs dfs -stat* to bring epoch time and then programming a filter

```
cat <fileWithFilePaths> | xargs -I ^ -P 15 sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$(hdfs dfs -stat "%n,%Y,%b" ^)"'>output1

awk 'BEGIN{beginDE=ENVIRON["beginDataEpoch"]; endDE=ENVIRON["endDataEpoch"]; FS="@"} {if ($1 >= beginDE && $1 <= endDE) print $0}' output1
```

But later realized its using hdfs stat is expensive function. So now I am using *hdfs dfs -ls* to bring the file time but its in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm format, thus I am seeking help in regards to change this in epoch time for calculations down the line.

Comment: Are your times in GMT, or do you know the time zone? What you're asking for isn't possible using traditional awk, but might be possible using gawk or functions in bash. That said, I'm voting to close this question, as it appears that you're asking for a solution rather than for help with your code. If you actually HAVE some code that needs help, please [add it to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51662934/edit), and I will happily withdraw my close vote.

Comment: I am using local time(EST). Yes I am asking for help with my code, and the snippet provided is similar to what I have in my code. Being said that I do not understand why my question is being down-voted. The solutions provided below are very much helpful for my usecase.

Comment: The catch is, you didn't provide a snippet of code in your question. You're getting downvotes and close votes because your question appears to be a request for a hand-out rather than starting with your own attempt to solve this. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51662934/edit) to show your work so far. Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people answering know where your challenge lies.

Answer (score 2):

If your log file is large, this GNU `awk` command will be much faster than a `bash` loop calling the external command `date` for each line:

```
gawk -vFS=, -vOFS=, '{ $1 = mktime(gensub("[-:]", " ", "g", $1)) } 1'
```

- The first comma-delimited field is replaced with the result of `mktime`, a function (a GNU extension) that returns its parameter as a number of seconds since EPOCH.
- `gensub` (a GNU extension) is used to turn "`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`" into "`YYYY MM DD hh mm ss`" which is the format expected by `mktime()`.
- The final `1` is a mere TRUE condition that outputs the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` along with its builtin `gensub`, `mktime` and `sub` to accomplish the same thing, e.g.

```
$ awk -F, '{ str=$0; sub($1, mktime(gensub(/[-:]/, " ", "g", $1)), str); print str }' file
1415606403,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user2,192.168.203.63,10.146.124.73,59996,22
1415606407,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user1,172.24.31.10,172.32.1.1,48191,22
1415606411,LOGIN FAILED,AUTH,root,172.24.166.153,10.146.124.73,52506,22
```

**Explanation:**

- `gensub(/[-:]/, " ", "g", $1)` - replace all `'-'` and `':'` in the first field with spaces;
- `mktime(...)` - turn the resulting date into a *timestamp*;
- `str=$0; sub($1, ..., str);` - replace the first field with the timestamp, result in `str`; and finally
- `print str` - print it.

(**note:** Your timezone and my are 3-hours different. Your output should give you your desired results on your system. You can also adjust `mktime` for Daylight Savings (if needed) and you can use the builtin `strftime` with the `utc-flag` to adjust for UTC.)

Comment: True, I am also suffering from this behavior these days in forums, I have up-voted this nice and well explained answer now.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be semi random. There are always some people that don't understand we are all here to learn and help each other do that, but instead take it as a like or dislike issue -- which misses the purpose for the site and discounts the learning that could be had. It has gotten better since it begin costing the downvoter a point to downvote, but there is still room for improvement.

Comment: `^1` for posting an awk answer instead of a shell loop :-)!

Comment: I can't speak for the downvoter, but I can't help but notice that this answer is technically incorrect. `gensub` and `mktime` are NOT part of awk, they are part of gawk. I don't see anything in the question to suggest what OS or variety of awk the OP is using, so I'd expect answers either to meet the basic criteria specified in the question, or to be explicit with regard to limitations. Not everyone speaks your dialect.

Comment: Yes this was on Linux and thus gawk, so that should be included for completeness.

Comment: What was your hint that this was on Linux? It's certainly not mentioned in the question. Or are you assuming that Linux is the only place where people use bash? And even so, awk != gawk, the opening sentence of your answer is still incorrect.

Comment: @Graham - meaning the testing I did was on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I guess while read loop would be the simplest. 
The following:

```
while IFS=, read -r date rest; do
        printf "%s,%s\n" "$(date --date="$date" +%s)" "$rest"
done <<EOF
2014-11-10 02:00:03,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user2,192.168.203.63,10.146.124.73,59996,22
2014-11-10 02:00:07,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user1,172.24.31.10,172.32.1.1,48191,22
2014-11-10 02:00:11,LOGIN FAILED,AUTH,root,172.24.166.153,10.146.124.73,52506,22
EOF
```

Will output:

```
1415581203,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user2,192.168.203.63,10.146.124.73,59996,22
1415581207,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user1,172.24.31.10,172.32.1.1,48191,22
1415581211,LOGIN FAILED,AUTH,root,172.24.166.153,10.146.124.73,52506,22
```

Comment: The `date` command doesn't include a `--date` option on my system. Can you adjust your solution so that it's more portable, or limited to the languages included in the question?

Comment: Maybe `date -d "$date" +%s`?

Comment: Nope. [This is the `date` I'm using.](http://man.freebsd.org/date) The `-f` option would be used to interpret a date from a predictable format, and `-v` could be used to apply adjustments.

Comment: Och cool, you have openbsd. Try smth like `date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' "$date" +%s` ?

Comment: Sure, or even `date -j -f '%F %T' "$date" '+%s'`. But more to the point, what operating system is the OP using? He/she didn't say, provided no sample code that would hint, and asked for a bash/awk solution. Rather than dealing with the unknowns from this poorly asked question, I'd suggest voting to close it, with some encouragement to the OP to either improve this question or ask a better one next time.

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when I needed to convert the date to unix time in some historical stock data. Used this `sed` and `date` command. Please note, that this only works on Linux (GNU implementation of `sed` and `date`).

```
simon@debian:~/Downloads$ cat inputFile
2014-11-10 02:00:03,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user2,192.168.203.63,10.146.124.73,59996,22
2014-11-10 02:00:07,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user1,172.24.31.10,172.32.1.1,48191,22
2014-11-10 02:00:11,LOGIN FAILED,AUTH,root,172.24.166.153,10.146.124.73,52506,22
simon@debian:~/Downloads$
simon@debian:~/Downloads$
simon@debian:~/Downloads$
simon@debian:~/Downloads$ sed 's/20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/echo `date --date="&" +"%s"`/e' inputFile > output
simon@debian:~/Downloads$
simon@debian:~/Downloads$
simon@debian:~/Downloads$
simon@debian:~/Downloads$ cat output 
1415602803,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user2,192.168.203.63,10.146.124.73,59996,22
1415602807,LOGIN SUCCESS,AUTH,user1,172.24.31.10,172.32.1.1,48191,22
1415602811,LOGIN FAILED,AUTH,root,172.24.166.153,10.146.124.73,52506,22
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/25791864)