# How can I convert date to epoch for squid proxy log?

Tags: date, command-line, epoch, squid

Hello everyone I am a network admin and studying how to convert human-readable dates to epoch such that I can import them to log analysis tools such as webalizer.

### Original

**[Wed Nov 17 17:00:00 2021]**.014   1786 10.107.54.55 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3964 CONNECT website.1.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/104.43.65.221 -

### Convert to

**1637139600**.014   1786 10.107.54.55 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3964 CONNECT website.1.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/104.43.65.221 -

I have basic UNIX knowledge but not strong.. I trying to follow this post [How can I convert date in a column to a epoch timestamp in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662934/how-can-i-convert-date-in-a-column-to-a-epoch-timestamp-in-bash) but unsuccessful. Would anyone help me, please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I finally can do it by reference to [Convert date to epoch time using AWK in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965658/convert-date-to-epoch-time-using-awk-in-linux) , and using `cut` command :-)

```sh
cut -b 2-400 log.txt | awk -F ']' '{ OFS = FS; command="date -d " "\"" $1 "\"" " +%s";command | getline $1; close(command); print $1 $2}'
```